# Hiding specific files in TextMate

Tags: java, jar, jruby, textmate

I do a lot of JRuby on Rails apps, and we have a fair amount of Java .jar dependencies.  These become quite annoying in textmate as it really muddies up my lib directory, and I never (obviously) need to actually open these files.

Can someone tell me how I might hide .jar files from my file listing in Textmate??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify File Pattern regex in :

```
TextMate-->Preferences-->Advanced-->FolderReferences
```

You just have to add `|\.(jar)` to your regex:

```
!(/\.(?!htaccess)[^/]*|\.(tmproj|o|pyc)|\.(jar)|/Icon\r|/svn-commit(\.[2-9])?\.tmp)$
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.wil-linssen.com/musings/entry/getting-.hidden-files-to-appear-in-the-textmate-project-drawer/).

Comment: any way of doing this for only one specific textmate project?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for a specific Textmate project too:

1. Save the project somewhere, for example in `myproject.tmproj`.
2. Make sure the project isn't open in Textmate (otherwise Textmate will overwrite your changes when you close the project)
3. Open up the `myproject.tmproj` file with a **different** text editor
4. Add a pattern for the files you want to ignore to the `<string>` value on the line immediately following the `regexFolderFilter` line. In this case you would add `|\.jar` just before the `)$</string>`.
5. Save the file.
6. Re-open the project in Textmate.

You can also open the `.tmproj` file in step 3 with Textmate if you use the command line command `mate`, too.